# How do I find the equation with a given set of x and y values?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

```
x=0.0    y=0.02
x=0.02   y=0.01
x=0.03   y=0.005
x=0.035  y=0.0025
x=0.05   y=0.0
```

I'm creating a calculator program for my personal specific needs. Above is an example of x and y pairs, where x is always known and y needs to be discovered with a mathematical formula/equation. How do I find the equation so I can use it to find the y with any known x?

Comment: Interpolation? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Moo Could you elaborate a bit more? What is interpolation and how can it help me find the formula?

Comment: There are tons of functions that can take these values, with really different behaviours, and none of these are particularly interesting if you don't require anything more

Comment: This is very vague.  Infinitely many functions pass through these points.  There's a quartic polynomial that passes through them, for example.  Alternatively, there's a line that comes close, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Linear+Interpolation&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22LinearFitCalculator%22%2C+%22data2%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C.02%7D%2C%7B.02%2C.01%7D%2C%7B.03%2C.005%7D%2C%7B.035%2C.0025%7D%2C%7B.05%2C0%7D%7D%22).  Without a model underlying the data, it's hard to say more.

Comment: @RestInPeace: There are many forms, for example, http://math.iit.edu/~fass/578_ch6.pdf. You need to study these to determine which one suits your needs.

Comment: In the end, it comes down to *personal choice* what you do.  What you are asking for is non-standard and does not fit any particularly "*nice*" pattern, so do what you prefer.  You can match it as closely as you like or you can make it as simple as you like, but these two things conflict with one another.  Perhaps try playing [connect the dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_the_dots) and making a piecewise-defined function with each piece being a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between any $n$ points with distinct $x$ values, you can fit [a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) of degree at most $n-1$.  In this particular example, that works out to:

$$y = \frac{100000}{9}x^4 - \frac{8500}{9}x^3 + \frac{235}{9}x^2 - \frac{11}{15}x + \frac{1}{50}$$

Alternatively, you could *approximate* the function [with linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), giving the simpler equation.

$$y = \frac{-5}{12} x + \frac{3}{160}$$

This is a pretty good fit, with $r \approx -0.978945$.

There are plenty of other mathematical models you can choose from.  The general process is called [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting).

Comment: Something inaccurate (or wrong) here : "Polynomial of Degree **at most** $(n-1)$" : We might say that $(n-1)$ is **sufficient but not necessary** [ In other words : larger Degree also works In some cases, we might get a Polynomial of lower Degree. ]